# Function and inequality problem

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inequality

Let $f$ an ascending and convex function on $(0,+\infty)$. I must to prove that:

> $$ f(\vert \sin(x) \vert +3) -f(\vert \sin(x) \vert)< f(x+3)-f(x)  $$

I know that a solution of that is to define the function $T(x)=f(x+3)-f(x)   $  which is ascending and from the inequality $ \vert \sin(x) \vert <x $ we have the conclusion.

I wonder if there is more straight way, more arithmetical. For example if we could use the inequalities $ \vert \sin(x) \vert <x $ and $ \vert \sin(x) \vert +3 <x+3 $ and the fact that $f$ is ascending to prove that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, $f$ needs to be strictly convex for that strict inequality to hold. Think of $x\mapsto x$. Second, if you're wondering the inequality can be proven using only the fact that $f$ is increasing, then the answer is no. For example, take $x\mapsto \sqrt x$.

Comment: yes you can do!

Comment: How can I Deniska?

Answer (score 1):

we know that for $x\in(0,\infty)$
$$|\sin x|\leq x$$

as you will be knowing increasing (*ascending*) function retains inequality we get$$f(|\sin x|)\leq f(x)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)$$

similarly $$f(|\sin x|+3)\leq f(x+3)\,\,\,\,\,(2)$$

then $(2)-(1)\implies f(|\sin x|+3)-f(|\sin x|)\leq f(x+3)-f(x)$

**Note:**

We could subtract these inequalities as such because both $f(|\sin x|+3)-f(|\sin x|)$ and $f(x+3)-f(x)$ are not changing there signs. We can generalize this:

$a>b$,$\,\,\,c>d$ we could subtract theses inequalities iff $a-c>0$ and $b-d>0$ so $$a-c>b-d$$ holds only true if those conditions are satisfied or $$|a-c|>|b-d| $$ for any value of $a,b,c,d$

idea was given to me by *ramsay*